# Picture incorrectly positioned in the \AtBeginDocument macro (Beamer presentation)

Tags: beamer, positioning, includegraphics

I am trying to create a Beamer template with background images on the Title Page and on the Table of Content page.
I have set the background images, and it works as expected as you can see on the picture below, last slide.
But then I wanted to have these pages automatically added to the beamer document using the \AtBeginDocument macro, the background picture are moved down (first two slides):
[image]

I guess this is because Beamer rewrite the `\includegraphics` macro, but I'm not sure on how I can fix it in my code.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mytpl}[1][]
{
    \color{red}\inserttitle
    \color{red}\insertsubtitle
}

\defbeamertemplate*{background}{mydefault}{}

\defbeamertemplate*{background}{titlebg}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{duck}}

\defbeamertemplate*{background}{tocbg}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{duck}}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setbeamertemplate{background}[mydefault]}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{tocbg}[true]{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background}[tocbg]%
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
}
\makeatother%

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\AtBeginDocument{ 
\begingroup
    \begin{frame}[tocbg]
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\endgroup
\begingroup
\begin{frame}[tocbg]
 \color{red}{My second slide used for TOC later}
\end{frame}
\endgroup
}

\title{Test 1}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[tocbg]
 \color{red}{My second slide used for TOC later}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't do typesetting in \AtBeginDocument.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with the `begindocument/end` hook. This should be late enough that beamer has already calculated its page geometry etc.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mytpl}[1][]
{
    \color{red}\inserttitle
    \color{red}\insertsubtitle
}

\defbeamertemplate*{background}{mydefault}{}

\defbeamertemplate*{background}{titlebg}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{duck}}

\defbeamertemplate*{background}{tocbg}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{duck}}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setbeamertemplate{background}[mydefault]}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{tocbg}[true]{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background}[tocbg]%
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
}
\makeatother%

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{
\begingroup
    \begin{frame}[tocbg]
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\endgroup
\begingroup
\begin{frame}[tocbg]
 \color{red}{My second slide used for TOC later}
\end{frame}
\endgroup
}

\title{Test 1}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[tocbg]
 \color{red}{My second slide used for TOC later}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]